# data points with yerrors in pdfcairo terminal

Tags: terminal, size, gnuplot, datapoint

I am plotting data with y-errorbars on a pdfcairo terminal and have a problem to properly size the data points:

```
plot "test.data" u ($6) : 10 : 11 with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 t
```

ps 1 gives too large a point and decreasing ps gives strange results. Interestingly, on a windows terminal everything looks ok, but the pdfcairo terminal makes problems. What is wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to say "what is wrong" because we don't see what you get and we don't see what you expect. What is "properly", "too large", "strange", "ok" and "making problems"? Please post some example test data and the different graphs you are getting and exactly describe what you expect.

Comment: After some more experimenting I found that the problem arises if the data points are getting close to each other in x-direction. Then, for small pointsizes (ps ~ 0.5), there appears a white circular area around each point which shields the error bar from view. my data file is too large for showing it here (is there a way to upload?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. I see a problem also but I do not know what causes it.

**Workaround**
Plot the data twice, once to show the error bars and once to show the variable size points.  Here is a screenshot of the pdf output using gnuplot 5.4.4

```
set term pdfcairo
set output 'yerrorbar.pdf'

set sample 51
set xrange [0:1]

set key left reverse

plot '+' using 1:1:(0.2) with yerrorbar lc 'blue' pt 7 ps 0, \
     '+' using 1:1:1 with points lc 'blue' pt 7 ps variable
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ethan, this does it. This seems to be a problem with the pdfcairo terminal. Prt